# Javascript Error on getelementsbytagname

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, getelementsbytagname

```
for(x in tr)
{
    var td = tr[x].getElementsByTagName('td');
    if(isNaN((bids=parseInt(td[2].innerHTML))))bids=0;
}
```

Loop is working only for 1st iteration but in second iteration i received error td[2] is undefined whereas each Row(tr) contain eight 8 columns(td). More than 50 Tr.

I have tried a lot but so confusing. It should not be an error.

Comment: use x.getElementsByTagName('td') instead of tr[x].getElementsByTagName('td')

Answer (score 1):

If `tr` is not an `Object`, there is a chance it is picking up other properties in a `for...in` loop. If this is the case, `.getElementsByTagName` would not exist and would throw an exception.

If `tr` is an `Array`, you should be using a regular `for` loop instead.

Related: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

When you get errors like this, it's useful to take a look at your variables using the Web Inspector (Chrome/Safari) or Firebug (Firefox).  Put a debugging breakpoint on the `var td =` line, and then look at the values of the variables.

It might be something to do with using a `for in` loop on an array, though. Change the outer loop to this and see if it works:

```
for (var x = 0, l = tr.length; x < l; ++x) {
  var td = tr[x]....
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are accessing an unintentional property of tr by not checking your `for in` loop.

Try:

```
for(x in tr)
{
    if(tr.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        var td = tr[x].getElementsByTagName('td');
        if(isNaN((bids=parseInt(td[2].innerHTML))))bids=0;
    }
}
```

For a quick explanation why, consider this: `"toString" in tr` will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i found some hidden column td under some of rows tr. Check your tr and td if display=none.

Answer (score 0):

Simple change your code as Dasarp said.

```
for(x in tr)
{
    var td = x.getElementsByTagName('td');
    if(isNaN((bids=parseInt(td[2].innerHTML))))bids=0;
}
```